# Get the distances to nearest neighbours in cktTree

Tags: python, scipy, spatial

coord_list is a numpyarray with x and y coordinates for some cities. Now I want to find both the indexes for all the nearest neighbours for each city within, but also the distance to all nearest neighbours within the radius in two separate numpyarrays. I get the indexes, but I can't find any way to get the distances. I tried to use **distance.cdist(coord_list, coord_list, 'euclidean')**, but I don't know how to use **ind** to get the right distances from **dist**. I've just started programming in Python.

```
def construct_graph_connections(coord_list, radius):

mytree = spatial.cKDTree(coord_list)
ind = mytree.query_ball_point(coord_list, radius)
dist = distance.cdist(coord_list, coord_list, 'euclidean')
return ind, distance
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give `distance.cdit()` the points you just computed by evaluating your `coord_list` in those indexes:

`dist = distance.cdist(coord_list, coord_list[ind], 'euclidean')`